# Why does this command to send emails work from the shell but not as a cron job?

Tags: centos, scripting, cron

I have a problem with cron jobs, I need to send email notification to users, I use this command

```
curl "http://example.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron">/dev/null 2>&1
```

When I run this command in shell it works, and it sends emails, but when I'm trying to set cron job it doesn't send emails:

Here is my /etc/cron.d :

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/
05,45 * * * * root run-parts /etc/cron.hourly
```

It is suposed to run /etc/cron.hourly cron job, here is /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Skip excecution unless the date has changed from the previous run
if test -r /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily; then
    day=`cat /var/spool/anacron/cron.daily`
fi
if [ `date +%Y%m%d` = "$day" ]; then
    exit 0;
fi

# Skip excecution unless AC powered
if test -x /usr/bin/on_ac_power; then
    /usr/bin/on_ac_power &> /dev/null
   if test $? -eq 1; then
    exit 0
     fi
fi
/usr/sbin/anacron -s
curl "http://example.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron">/dev/null 2>&1
```

Here is cron log, it shows that cron job is running

```
Aug  2 16:45:01 u17669867 CROND[3164]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Aug  2 16:45:01 u17669867 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3164]: starting 0anacron
Aug  2 16:45:01 u17669867 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3173]: finished 0anacron
```

Maybe, there is something wrong in /etc/cron.hourly/0anacron ?

Comment: What are you expecting to generate the email ? example.com ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you append your code directly into the `0anacron` file??

That's what's wrong here; don't do that.

check the man page for anacron:

> Anacron can be used to execute commands periodically, with a frequency
>   specified in days.  Unlike cron(8), it does not assume that the
>   machine is running continuously.

Clearly, this is not related to what you are having in mind with your emails, and if you check the script, you can see that there's a good chance it script would've `exited 0` before coming to your task.

Anyway, try putting your

```
curl "http://example.com/index.php?option=com_community&task=cron">/dev/null 2>&1
```

Inside a file named something like `/etc/cron.hourly/1send_emails`. Chown it to root and make executable.

The file will then be run on an hourly basis and it should be logged in your cron log in a similar fashion to the anacron job.

If you want to specify your own cron expression, or run as different user than root, put a similar file with your line prefixed with cron expression and user to run as before the job to run in `/etc/cron.d` instead.